# Conditional hyperlink

Tags: hyperref

I am generating a document based on a relatively big set of data (meaning; manual editing is no option). It concerns a pedigree, so a lot of repetitive (pattern wise) information.
One of the things I would like to do is to provide a link which is stored in a textfile, under the condition that this file exists. Something like

```
\IfFileExists{includes/I6.fs}{
    \href{\InputIfFileExists{includes/I6.fs}}{TheNameOfMyLink}
}{}
```

This does not work, however. I could check the existence of this file from the code, but this would mean that each and every time I add a link, I would need to rerun the program, regenerate the file, which is something I would like to avoid.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The `{}{}` branch statements are missing, in my point of view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that `\InputIfFileExists` will expand inside `\href`. 
You have to read the file content first to a macro and use that macro as link name in the 1st argument of `\href`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\newread\linkfilehandle

\newcommand{\DisplayLinkFromFile}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mylinkfile{}
  \IfFileExists{#1}{%
    \openin\linkfilehandle=#1
    \read\linkfilehandle to \mylinkfile
    \href{\mylinkfile}{#2}
    \closein\linkfilehandle
  }{%
    % Do nothing
  }
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\DisplayLinkFromFile{somestupidfile}{My nice link}

\end{document}
```

`somestupidfile.tex` just contains the line `http://tex.stackexchange.com`

Comment: This looks exactly like what I would like to do. However, this does not work on my system; I get the following error;  ! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@a ->\openin \linkfilehandle
                                      =includes/I6.fs \read \linkfilehandle ...
l.119 ...inkFromFile{includes/I6.fs}{My nice link} This might be related to my system, using LaTeX on cygwin, maybe filehandling is done differently....

Comment: Well, Windows is not my business. I can try on my notebook with TeXLive, however.

Comment: I got it to work using your example. I did not quite get it to work as a command, but I was able to slightly alter it. This is what I have done: define a \newread\linkfilehandle in the preamble (just like you did), but included the file handling in the document like this:   \IfFileExists{includes/I5753.fs}{
 \begin{flushright}
  \openin\linkfilehandle=includes/I5753.fs
  \readline\linkfilehandle to \myFile
  \href{\myFile}{My Nice Link}
  \closein\linkfilehandle
 \end{flushright}
}{}

Comment: @barrel: I don't understand how the `flushright` environment improves this  to make it compilable. You should notice a line skip, however?

Comment: No.. the flushright is just esthetic and I shouldn't have added it to my comment (was a copy and paste), it has nothing to do with the initial problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @barrel: Ah, now I see the difference: `\readline` instead of `\read`